# How to remove USB device from windows terminal (batch file)?

Tags: batch-file

How do I safely remove a USB device using the windows cmd terminal - without requesting user input?
It would be great if I can do it from a batch script :-)

Comment: And it would be great if the USB device can be plugged in later on - without issues

Comment: You can take a look at this code ==> http://pastebin.com/HNZtQafz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RemoveDrive](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/drivetools_e.html) to do this.

After you set up Enviorment Variables you can run `removedrive "Sandisk Extreme" -L`

Comment: How does RemoveDrive know which USB port it is? For example, if I have two USB memory sticks plugged in.